# Capacitor custom plugin swift - access viewController and original window from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, capacitor

I'm creating a capacitor plugin but I have issues passing some params to a third party framework.

The method should receive:

- restoreViewController: original viewController
- window: original window from AppDelegate

and then I should update the AppDelegate window. I have a code sample of the implementation:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

var window: UIWindow?

method(
  restoreViewController: appDelegate.window.rootViewController,
  window: &window
)

 appDelegate?.window = window
```

But this doesn't work. The appDelegate is <App.AppDelegate> and it returns. So, i tried with

```
 guard let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window
 window?.rootViewController
```

and

```
 self.bridge?.viewController
```

But it throws an error

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <...>.
```

I really don't know what to pass and update, I'm not very skilled on swift.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let window = self.bridge?.viewController?.view.window
}
```